# Add multiple plots monthwise on same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a line plot in matplotlib with different line representing different month

I have the code:

```
if(month=='12'):
cursor=cnx.cursor()
query="Select q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10 from table where month_id=12;"
cursor.execute(query)
result=list(cursor.fetchall())
for i in result:
    dec=list(i)

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):    

    ax.plot(dec,    

            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])
if(month=='01'):
cursor=cnx.cursor()
query="Select q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10 from table where month_id=1;"
cursor.execute(query)
result=list(cursor.fetchall())
for i in result:
    jan=list(i)
for rank, column in enumerate(majors):    

    ax.plot(jan,    

            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[1])
```

But when I change the month  to january .the plot for month 12 vanishes and plot for january comes up..I need both of the plots to be on same graph.Please help me with this.

Comment: are your data spanning very different ranges? The autoscaling in matplotlib can make it appear as if the older plot has disappeared. For instance, if december had 10 points and january had 10000, since you are not providing an explicit x range, the december plots will all be squished (and nearly invisible) near the vertical Y axis.

Comment: No,that is not the case with me.I only have ~10 points to plot on each month..